# Adding group in Swing shifts horizontal position

Tags: java, forms, swing

I'm trying to make a simple Swing GUI for a console app, and usually use .NET so much of this is new to me and I'm trying to understand how it works.

I have the following horizontal setting for the Swing form:

```
 javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(tempTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(celsiusLabel))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(convertButton)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(fahrenheitLabel)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                     .addComponent(importDDPathField)
                     .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                     .addComponent(importDDLabel))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
```

Then the following for the vertical layout:

```
layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] {convertButton, tempTextField, importDDPathField});

        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(tempTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(celsiusLabel))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(convertButton)
                    .addComponent(fahrenheitLabel))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(importDDPathField)
                    .addComponent(importDDLabel))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        pack();
```

I can't see why the form is adding the last group way off to the right, as shown below:

[image]

I added the third group in the same manner as the first two, but the positioning is being offset somehow, and I'm not sure how.

Comment: `GroupLayout` isn't really meant for hand coding and is generally quite difficult to update/modify, just saying

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yea, if I intended to make a project out of this I would take it more seriously, just wanted something quick and dirty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might have an extra `)` after `fahrenheitLabel` in the horizontal layout code.  It looks like that's preventing the import-file widgets from being inside the same parallel group as your other widgets.